# Animate a button in JavaScript to bring up a modal dialog box from the button to the center of the screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I have a very specific trick I'm trying to perform in JavaScript, and I'm sure there are libraries out there that will allow me to do this, but my searching for a precise solution has failed so far.

I have a web page that has a "Login" button in the top right corner of the screen.  When the user clicks the button, I will display a CSS modal dialog box on the center of the screen that allows the user to type in their authentication information.  The CSS dialog box is all set, there's just one piece missing:

I want to add an animation when the user clicks on the login button that shows the modal box "opening" from the Login button to the center of the screen to help draw the user's eye to where it is supposed to go next. The animation should feel similar to when a window is minimized to/unminimized from the Windows taskbar.

Can anyone point me to a JavaScript library that has this functionality? Thanks so much!

Comment: You can use a `scale` `transform` and `opacity`, but I don't think there's anything pre-built out there.

Comment: You may not get the exact animation what you are looking, but if you use jquery you might get good animation effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my attempt :-p http://jsfiddle.net/zAzqB/

Utilizes jQuery and the [jQuery Easing](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/) library (just to make the effect smoother… the easing library can be left out and it will still work fine). The element that should be animated is cloned while the animation happens, and the original is moved into a clipping element that animates to the final position.

Comment: I like it! I like it a lot! It's several lines more code than just using jQueryUI's transfer effect, but you've built a really clean way to show the graphics of the dialog box itself as it "opens up" from the clicked button.  Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately, when I tried to integrate this logic into my actual code, it didn't work well in my Chrome browser.  It seems that when the modal dialog box uses absolute positioning to center itself above everything else in the page, it breaks the animation such that after clicking the launch button, the dialog simply "appears" in the destination location at the end of the animation timer.  Thanks for the attempt, though!

Comment: Ah :-p See [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zAzqB/11/). The problem is that while the absolute element is inside the clipping plane (which is also an absolute element), it appears `top` and `left` from the `top` and `left` of the clipping plane (outside the clipped area). The trick is to make the dialog element `position: static;` while inside the clipping plane (made possible by adding an extra class to the clipping plane and `.clippingPlane #dialog { position: static; }` to the CSS).

Answer (score 2):

I think I just found what I was looking for in jQueryUI:

There is a 'transfer' effect that will animate a box outline from one element to another. While this will not show the modal dialog itself expanding out from the button, it should achieve the objective of drawing the user's eye from point A to point B.  I'd love to hear about other solutions though!

jQueryUI Transfer demo:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/default.html (Change the select box from 'Blind' to 'Transfer' then click 'Run effect'.)

jQueryUI Transfer described:
http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Transfer

Answer (score 0):

I used JQuery Mobile SimpleDialog2 recently and was quite happy with it.
I did notice that the animation worked for chrome, but not for FF though.

http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/demos/string.html

Comment: That is nice! The current focus is on a desktop UI, but if and when we are looking to build a mobile version, we will definitely keep this in mind, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<style>
.clickBrn { height:50px; width:100%; text-align:right;}
.popUp {height:100px; width:500px; margin:auto; background:#333; color:#FFF; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:18px; text-align:center; line-height:100px; margin-top:100px;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="clickBrn">
<input type="button" name="btn" id="btn" value="Click" />
</div>
<div id="iAM" class="popUp"> </div>

<script>

$("#iAM").hide();
$("#btn").click(function()
{
//document.getElementById('iAM').style.marginLeft="400px";
$("#iAM").css( { marginLeft : "400px" } );
$("#iAM").show(1000);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```